# Jasper Json nested lists

Tags: jasper-reports

I'm new in Jasper reports, so I'll write my whole task, if it's allowed..

I'm trying to parse json data to print in it PDF. Data is coming from oracle DB, written in CLOB column, so I have list of json-clob records.

I have nested lists json (and clob) data, so I can't build 3 stair nested report with my jasper experience. I have json structure like this:

```
{
  title: 'Main Title',
  blocks: [{
    title: 'Inner Title',
    items: [{
      key: '1',
      value: 'some text'
    }, {
      key: '2',
      value: 'some other text'
    }]
  }, {
    text: 'here may be other fields (text, not title)'
  }]
}
```

For this json data, I want to get this result in PDF (just simple output):

```
Main Title
Inner Title
1 some text
2 some other text
here may be other fields (text, not title)
```

Firstly, I use CLOB converting in json source ( script:

```
< dataSourceExpression >
  < ![CDATA[new net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JsonQLDataSource(new ByteArrayInputStream($F{JSON_CLOB_RECORD}.getBytes("UTF-8")))]] >
< /dataSourceExpression >
```

source: [nested jasper subreports with json datasource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30588411/nested-jasper-subreports-with-json-datasource#answer-37015082) ).

After that, I use jr:list and textfield to print main titles. And I'm done, don't know how to continue.

I searched nested lists (jr:list) but nothing, can't fit to my task.

P.S. I have subDataset for parsing data from CLOB to json with fields title (java.lang.String) and blocks (I tried here java.util.Collection and ArrayList but errors occurred, than I wrote java.lang.Object. Is it necessary to write blocks field in this subDataset?). I also added subDataset for blocks list, is it needed? And if yes, so I have to add items subDataset too, right? Also, I tried to add subReport after main title textfield, for blocks list and added dataSourceExpression but can't continue.

Need some help.

Comment: Please add the desired output for each CLOB record.

Comment: Just simple output, I added the result after Json data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest using a subreport, instead of a list or nested lists, because you gain more flexibility in this case.

In the main report you should discard the list element and the dataset and use a subreport, something like:

```
<subreport>
    <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="550" height="50" uuid="37861aca-d444-4aec-ad03-baa310540327"/>
    <subreportParameter name="JSON_INPUT_STREAM">
        <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[new ByteArrayInputStream($F{JSON_CLOB_RECORD}.getBytes("UTF-8"))]]></subreportParameterExpression>
    </subreportParameter>
    <subreportExpression><![CDATA["Subreport.jasper"]]></subreportExpression>
</subreport>
```

Here we only need the `JSON_INPUT_STREAM` so that the subreport will construct a  dataSource based on the query and its language.

Case 1. If you are mostly interested in the `items` key, then the subreport(Subreport.jrxml) could be pretty basic like so:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="Subreport" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="a3dd10f8-b28c-4c11-b582-9b169e8aa417">
    <queryString language="jsonql">
        <![CDATA[..items.*]]>
    </queryString>
    <field name="mainTitle" class="java.lang.String">
        <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.jsonql.field.expression" value="$.title"/>
    </field>
    <field name="key" class="java.lang.String">
        <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.jsonql.field.expression" value="key"/>
    </field>
    <field name="value" class="java.lang.String">
        <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.jsonql.field.expression" value="value"/>
    </field>
    <field name="blockTitle" class="java.lang.String">
        <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.jsonql.field.expression" value="^^.title"/>
    </field>
    <background>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </background>
    <detail>
        <band height="90" splitType="Stretch">
            <textField>
                <reportElement isPrintRepeatedValues="false" x="0" y="30" width="100" height="30" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true" uuid="172de051-3d2c-4458-b01e-ab06e4e1bb3b"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{blockTitle}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement isPrintRepeatedValues="false" x="0" y="0" width="100" height="30" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true" uuid="94f57756-a5a8-402f-ad23-7cdbe2a00e59"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{mainTitle}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="0" y="60" width="100" height="30" uuid="7dbbdfd8-5a0e-4288-ae39-21f13cd4d921"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{key} + " " + $F{value}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </detail>
</jasperReport>
```

Notice the `isPrintRepeatedValues="false"` and the `isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true"` properties that remove the duplicates and the lines so that you get the desired output.

I've simulated your case with a serialized JSON and got the following:
[image: sample output]

Case 2. If you are interested in all the `blocks` object data you would have to land on the `blocks` item in your query and create a list/subreport for the `items` key, something like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="Report" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="a3dd10f8-b28c-4c11-b582-9b169e8aa417">
    <subDataset name="BlockItemsDataset" uuid="83c1b8ed-e880-4474-a809-39d95277341f">
        <field name="key" class="java.lang.String">
            <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.jsonql.field.expression" value="key"/>
        </field>
        <field name="value" class="java.lang.String">
            <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.jsonql.field.expression" value="value"/>
        </field>
    </subDataset>
    <queryString language="jsonql">
        <![CDATA[blocks]]>
    </queryString>
    <field name="mainTitle" class="java.lang.String">
        <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.jsonql.field.expression" value="$.title"/>
    </field>
    <field name="blockTitle" class="java.lang.String">
        <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.jsonql.field.expression" value="title"/>
    </field>
    <background>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </background>
    <detail>
        <band height="91" splitType="Stretch">
            <textField>
                <reportElement isPrintRepeatedValues="false" x="0" y="0" width="100" height="30" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true" uuid="94f57756-a5a8-402f-ad23-7cdbe2a00e59"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{mainTitle}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement isPrintRepeatedValues="false" x="0" y="30" width="100" height="30" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true" uuid="172de051-3d2c-4458-b01e-ab06e4e1bb3b"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{blockTitle}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <componentElement>
                <reportElement x="0" y="61" width="200" height="30" uuid="7a94d84d-d58e-4508-b143-3704fa7f5cd3"/>
                <jr:list xmlns:jr="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/components.xsd" printOrder="Vertical">
                    <datasetRun subDataset="BlockItemsDataset" uuid="a866f955-7594-4fb9-9bb2-936282963dea">
                        <dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[((net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JsonQLDataSource)$P{REPORT_DATA_SOURCE}).subDataSource("items")]]></dataSourceExpression>
                    </datasetRun>
                    <jr:listContents height="30" width="200">
                        <textField>
                            <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="200" height="30" uuid="36a771fa-f949-4c69-a62c-1df0c610a2d3"/>
                            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{key} + " " + $F{value}]]></textFieldExpression>
                        </textField>
                    </jr:listContents>
                </jr:list>
            </componentElement>
        </band>
    </detail>
</jasperReport>
```

Comment: It's very cool you did here! But, there is one bug here - could you build source like this: In my Json data, up here, please, remove the second record from blocks array and copy the first record (and change its values, not to be removed by duplicate remover); in report preview, only first record is printing.. :(

Comment: If more than one object in the `blocks` array has the `items` key, then you should go with `..items.*` as your query string. However, this should work in all cases. Try that and if all is well, I'll edit my answer.

Comment: Yes, it's working now! But I found one another case: I have record in 'blocks' list in my Json data example, which has only one field, 'text' (I added <field name="blockText"> in script like 'blockTitle'); it is not appearing, but if I add 'items' with filled list (just empty record: {} is enough), then it is printing; but I have only 'text' field.. Please, help me in this case too and it will be the most perfect answer from you.. :)

Comment: As I think, the reason is <![CDATA[..items]]> . If the record exists, then it works.. I tried to build more nested subReports, can it be done? I tried to figure SubSubReport for blocks and for items one level down too, but can't call data in down level subReport from upper one.. Firstly here was JSON_INPUT_STREAM and getting bytes.. How it will be in sub sub reports for nested lists?

Comment: I've added a "Case 2" that is more general and left the initial subreport in 'Case 1' with the `..items.*` query.

Comment: For now I can print everything that I wanted to (I added 'text' field here too). Thanks a lot.  It is very nice way using property selectors.